# Github Actions with ACT - Accessing a service from inside a docker container

Tags: docker, github-actions

How can you access a service, in this case mysql, if you use a docker image in a container for runing the steps?
The services don't seem to be available in the docker container.

```
name: Docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  namea:
    name: Docker Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
    container:
      image: public-docker-image
      options: --user root
      ports:
        - 80:80
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup
        run: |
          mysql -h127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What is that `public-docker-image`? The workflow steps will be running inside that container and using 127.0.0.1 means that MySQL is running there but it's not. It's running outside as configured under `services`. [MySQL is preinstalled on `ubuntu-latest` runner](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#mysql), you can use that instead if it works for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. The public-docker-image is just a placeholder, cause it's a general question unspecific to a particular one. I had this problem a couple of times already.

I can't use the ubuntu-latest runner MySQL unfortunately. Is there no way to make the services-service accessible to the container?

Comment: Check these examples: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-redis-service-containers#running-jobs-in-containers and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers#running-jobs-in-containers

Comment: With correct host, you should be able to work with MySQL.

Comment: So in my example above the service is called "mysql" but when I use that string for the host in the container, like in the examples from the links, it only tells me that the server host "mysql" is unknown.

Comment: Please add what you tried in your question along with that error under an UPDATE heading.

Comment: Ok, nevermind....it probably works but I am trying to run the workflow locally with act. And it turns out services are just not supported: https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/173

Should I put this as a solution to this SO question?

Comment: Well, your question didn't have any mention about `act`. You need to edit that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that services are simply not supported with ACT: https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/173